# How to bind tooltip display/activated property to focus event rather than the hover event in JavaFX2?

Tags: java, user-interface, event-handling, javafx-2

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.geometry.Insets;
import javafx.geometry.Pos;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.control.OverrunStyle;
import javafx.scene.control.PasswordField;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;
import javafx.scene.control.Tooltip;
import javafx.scene.layout.GridPane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class BindTooltipToFocusEvent extends Application {
  @Override
  public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {
    stage.setTitle("How to bind tooltip to focus event?");
    GridPane grid = new GridPane();
    grid.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
    grid.setHgap(10);
    grid.setVgap(5);
    grid.setPadding(new Insets(25, 25, 25, 25));
    grid.add(new Label("Email"), 0, 0);
    grid.add(new TextField(), 0, 1);
    grid.add(new Label("Password"), 0, 2);

    Tooltip tooltip = new Tooltip("Paswords must contain 1-50 characters, etc...");
    tooltip.setWrapText(true);
    tooltip.setTextOverrun(OverrunStyle.ELLIPSIS);
    PasswordField pf = new PasswordField();
    pf.setPromptText("Password");
    pf.setTooltip(tooltip);
    grid.add(pf, 0, 3);

    stage.setScene(new Scene(grid, 300, 275));
    stage.sizeToScene();
    stage.show();
  }
  public static void main(String[] args) { launch(); }
}
```

Running the provided example application demonstrates the default tooltip behavior in Java FX to display the tooltip on the mouse hover event. Hovering for a second or two over the password field will cause the tooltip to be displayed. I would rather have the tooltip visible while the user is entering their password rather than while they (might) hover over the field with their mouse.

How can this behavior be changed such that the tooltip will be displayed while the password field has focus?

I know it would be possible to add another label to the user interface and modify its visibility property based on when the password field has focus. This question is not asking for a workaround to the example use case. I would like to know specifically how to make the tooltip visible while the parent field has focus.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To achieve that you should manage the tooltip's visibility and position yourself:

```
@Override
public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {
    stage.setTitle("How to bind tooltip to focus event?");
    GridPane grid = new GridPane();
    grid.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
    grid.setHgap(10);
    grid.setVgap(5);
    grid.setPadding(new Insets(25, 25, 25, 25));
    grid.add(new Label("Email"), 0, 0);
    grid.add(new TextField(), 0, 1);
    grid.add(new Label("Password"), 0, 2);

    final Tooltip tooltip = new Tooltip("Paswords must contain 1-50 characters, etc...");
    tooltip.setWrapText(true);
    tooltip.setTextOverrun(OverrunStyle.ELLIPSIS);
    final PasswordField pf = new PasswordField();
    pf.setPromptText("Password");
    //pf.setTooltip(tooltip);
    pf.focusedProperty().addListener(new ChangeListener<Boolean>() {
        @Override
        public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends Boolean> observable, Boolean oldValue, Boolean newValue) {
            if (newValue) {
                tooltip.show(pf, //
                        // popup tooltip on the right, you can adjust these values for different positions
                        pf.getScene().getWindow().getX() + pf.getLayoutX() + pf.getWidth() + 10, //
                        pf.getScene().getWindow().getY() + pf.getLayoutY() + pf.getHeight());
            } else {
                tooltip.hide();
            }
        }
    });
    grid.add(pf, 0, 3);

    stage.setScene(new Scene(grid, 300, 275));
    stage.sizeToScene();
    stage.show();
}
```

One drawback of this approach is that the tooltip will be stayed on the screen even when the window is moved/dragged to the different place.